# Second order ODE with boundary conditions using python

Tags: python, odeint

I am trying to solve equation in the form of `y'' + ay' + by + c = 0` (second order differential equation) in python using `odeint`.  As I understood, `odeint` works only with initial conditions in the form of y(0) = y1, y'(0) = y2. Whereas my conditions are boundary: y'(0) = 0, y'(pi/4) = 0. Is there any way to use `odeint` with such conditions? Here is the code I have:

```
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import numpy as np

def lagrange(x, teta):
  y = x[0]
  dy = x[1]  
  xdot = [[],[]]
  xdot[0] = dy
  xdot[1] = (y + dy**2*y*(y**2 + dy**2)**(-1.5) + y*(y**2+dy**2)**(-0.5))/((y**2+dy**2)**(-0.5) - dy**2*(y**2+dy**2)**(-1.5))
  return xdot

phi = np.linspace(0,np.pi/4,100)

U = odeint(lagrange, [u1_0, u2_0], phi)
```

Comment: You can use shooting method to solve boundary value problems with initial value problem solvers.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shooting_method 
It will require additional programming though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The official [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.odeint.html) states that it solves the initial value problem for stiff or non-stiff systems of first order ode-s. Therefore it cannot solve boundary value problems.

You will most likely need implement the finite difference method, finite element method or shooting method to solve the problem.

I would personally recommend the finite difference method as it essentially consists of adding 3 diagonal matrics (2 of which are tridiagonal), setting up a solution vector and using a linear solver.

If you need some help setting it up, I wrote a [diffusion-advection](https://gitlab.com/snippets/1700960) solver not too long ago for matlab which you could port and extend to include the reaction term (should be b*identity matrix).

Depending on your value of a, you may also need to implement artificial diffusion (in case that the peclet number is too large).